# New Hosting - Permission problems?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, permissions, chmod

I've been developing a site under a test server that I share with other people. Once I finished everything, I got hosting at NearlyFreeSpeech.net and switched the nameservers over. I had to change all the URLs over as I had a specific folder on the test server. I did this all by hand instead of Search and Replace, so I'm fairly certain everything is correct.

However, I've been having a series of problems and they all seem related. At first I was unable to access certain files because of a permissions problem. I was getting a kind of MySQL "permission denied" kind of error. I also refer to a lot of PHP files that check certain conditions (desired username free, is password correct, etc.) and for some reason, many of those are always returning the same exact "true" false even though the code is the same as I had it on the test server. After turning off those JS validations, I've just been trying to login/register and many of those return unwarranted errors in the server side validation, so something is definitely going wrong.

I ended up just setting every file to CHMOD 777 some time in between all this, and it got rid of a few errors. However, I'm still having those validation errors and when it occasionally logs me in, it doesn't start the session.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

A specific case as an example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM registerusers WHERE username='$username'";
$res = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
   $output = false;
} else {
   $output = true;
}
   echo json_encode($output);
```

This always returns 1 row. In my original script I used `if (mysql_num_rows > 0)`, and it works fine. However, here, that code does not work. By changing it to `==`, I can determine that it is always returning 1 and does does that clause. It returns 1 if the username exists or not. I am absolutely stumped and can't really see how I would get such an error from just changing hosting.

Comment: How did you transfer the files? I remember having some permission problems (on images though) when i, by script, transfered files with ftp_put, and had the type as FTP_ASCII instead of FTP_BINARY.

Comment: MySQL 'permission denied' is more likely due to database credentials being wrong - check those first. If you are having trouble with your sessions you may have output something to the browser before starting the session. You may need to debug this problem on your development machine first.

Comment: The question is really vague, but if you have Mysql errors related to permissions, you may also want to check stored procedure/function/trigger bodies. When you create sp, it adds `definer=[username]`(even if you didn't specify it explicitly) , and mysql user from the old system may not exist in the new... I had such problems in the past during migration process.

Comment: Also, temporarily turn on all errors and warnings using [error_reporting](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to see if your php config on the new server is causing problems. Lastly, see if you can get away with permissions 644 on a shared server - you don't want to give 'world' access to anything.

Comment: @halfer, if I just replicate all the permissions I had on my test server, would that work?

Comment: @MarkHünermundJensen, I just downloaded all the files from my test server and then uploaded them from there to the new hosting. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: did you create a new DB scheme or used the same one you had on your test-server ?

Comment: It might help, but (a) they could have been overly broad and so present a security risk, and (b) this may not even be the source of your problem.

Comment: Incidentally, are your "unwarranted errors" actual PHP errors, or just validation failure messages from your application? If the latter, could you be relying on a legacy feature like register_globals?

Comment: @halfer I see. I included a specific example of the type of problem I'm having frequently so maybe we can determine what the root of all this is.

Comment: @halfer the unwarranted errors are just when things aren't working as intended. I'm not getting any actual errors, but rather things are, for example in the original post, always returning true when the code is exactly the same.

Comment: @alfasin Are you referring to the information_schema? I had a database for that in my test server, but I didn't transfer it over. The new phpmyadmin already had one and also another one titled "mysql". I didn't do anything with them and just imported the database I created for site content. Should I do something with the other databases?

Comment: Got an update for us, @MarkLyons? I think alfasin's suggestion will help you sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using mysql_fetch_row() instead of mysql_num_rows() and see what is returned.
Please update us - I'm curious!

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer an a strategy here for fixing, since from the original post and the comments, it is probably not possible to determine what the issue is with any certainty. The way I would tackle it assumes that the web application works fine in a development environment, and worked fine on the previous server. The issue of failing validation is only happening on the new server.

I would add in statements into the live environment that let you see what your application (or, PHP) is seeing. For example, a query string value that is being read from an environment variable might have to be read from a different env var on your new server. If that is the case, that might point to an unusual php.ini configuration.

You can do this in a number of ways. For me, I sometimes log onto the server in question via SSH and bring the file into nano (or whatever text-based editor you have available). With this strategy, the ideal situation is to use your version control on the server for deployment - so if you use subversion, you can simply do `svn revert file.php` and you've removed your debug edits at a stroke.  However this may not be available for you if you are using shared hosting (I don't think you've said).

If you are on shared hosting, you could add in conditional debug statements depending on, say, the existence of a file in your home root. If this file exists, either public debug is activated (`print_r()` vars to screen then exit) or private debug (dump things to a server file so they can be FTPed back to you for analysis). I would do this on your dev machine, make sure it works, commit it to version control, send it up in your usual way, then remove from the current version once you're sure it's fixed.

Addendum: also, temporarily switch on error/warning reporting as I said in the comments. This might reveal an issue that seems obvious with hindsight.